# Is it possible to search in Google ads?

Tags: google-search, ads

I was wondering if there is a way to search only in google ads? Normally , google shows some advertisements related to the search term. Is it possible to just get these advertisements!. I mean, can we find out google advertisements related to a search term?

Answer (score 0):

No, It is not possible to find all google ads related to search term because google runs an auction of ad for each search term and ad results are displayed differently with each search term.However, You may be able to see some of them through adwords tool "Ad preview and Diagnosis"

If your purpose is competitor analysis then you can use "auction insight" or if you want to do analysis of search term then please use search term report in Google Adwords

Link for search term report -https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2472708?hl=en